# filter.commentAfter by Emmet in Sublime Text 3 not work

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

In Emmet by ST3, I tried to customize a little comment after giving tab when creating a label, for example #div or .span

I read that this was a solution in the settings of Emmet (Emmet.sublime-settings):

```
"preferences": {

    "filter.commentAfter"  : "<!-- <%= attr('id', '#') %> <%= attr('class', '.') %> -->",

    "filter.commentBefore" : "<!-- <%= attr('id', '#') %> <%= attr('class', '.') %> -->"
}
```

But not work. Please Help

Comment: Is this how your `Emmet.sublime-settings` looks like? Or it’s just a part of it?

Comment: Yes, so the file looks, thanks to @ionutvmi fix it and I could :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your User/Emmet.sublime-settings file make sure you have your structure like this

```
{
    "preferences": {
        "filter.commentAfter"  : "<!-- <%= attr('id', '#') %> <%= attr('class', '.') %> -->",
        "filter.commentBefore" : "<!-- <%= attr('id', '#') %> <%= attr('class', '.') %> -->"             
     }
}
```

and it should work.
Make sure you dont forget about the `|c` at the end

```
div#test.myclass|c
```

As an extra if you want to automatically add the `c` filter you should set your `syntaxProfiles` to something like this

```
{
    "preferences": {
    },
    "syntaxProfiles": {
        "html" : {
            // auto add the comments
            "filters": "html,c"
        }
    }
}
```

make sure it's on the same level as `preferences`

Comment: It works! Thank you @ionutvmi. 

Fails to add the `c` automatically. In that file I put this code?

Comment: Now it works, I had to restart the computer for the change to be effected. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to set this that it will only trigger on divs and not other elements.

`.test` expects `<div class="test"></div><!-- /.test -->`
`h4.test` expects `<h4 class="test"></div>`